# GitHub Action runner : Problem in configuring as a service

Tags: github, github-actions

I have self hosted runner. But my runner is not online always. Its turned off even though it's configured as a service. But my machine is up.

While starting the service it gives a below problem.

[image]

Expected output of service need to be like below:
[image]

Any hints?
Followed this page to configure  :https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/configuring-the-self-hosted-runner-application-as-a-service

Comment: Please copy/paste error messages instead of using a screenshot. This allows people with the same error message to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is with the connection to GitHub.

Some things to double check -

1. Make sure the host can connect to GitHub (running a ping should prove this)
2. Make sure the installation of the self hosted runner was done with the correct token.